# Couchbase, Spring & JPA

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jpa, couchbase

Can Couchbase work with JPA and Spring framework correctly?
Is there any documentation/website where I can find more information?
Any thing to be especially careful of when setting it up?

We are trying to build a web application that will need a quite large amount of data and best setup looks to be Couchbase with Spring and JPA to connect to the DB (in order to have another database plugged easily later). Also speed and accuracy would be two of the most important pieces of the app. and Couchbase seems to offer very good quality for both.

Comment: Find a JPA provider that provides support for persisting to Couchbase. To state the obvious, JPA is designed for use with RDBMS and certain aspects of the API are only suitable for use with an RDBMS.

Comment: So far I have not seen JPA provider for Couchbase. There is one for MongoDB noSQL JPA provider...but strangely not for CB. See http://hibernate.org/ogm perhaps they will add it in near future.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the spring data project if you already using spring, [it has support for couchbase](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-couchbase/).

Comment: though important to mention that this is then *not* JPA (what the OP requested)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to include Couchbase I would follow the like [@NimChimpsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106261/nimchimpsky) posted.

Note: not if this is spring boot you can use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.data.couchbase.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Alternatively there is probably a way to use JDBC ( not JPA ) to connect to Couchbase but I only recommend that if you want granular control of the configuration.